# Yahoo Pipes HTML Tables to JSON object array

Tags: html, json, yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to use Yahoo Pipes to turn multiple tables inside a DIV into an array of JSON objects.

Below is what I currently have. The HTML is being parsed fine.

[image]

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=cbd57c80e76b0a2973df0e8bbc357820

I want each of the table cells to be properties of of the JSON object. I believe this is possible with looping, however I can't figure out how to make this happen.

[image]

Comment: Provide the necessary data **in the question itself**. I'm not going to log into Yahoo to see what you currently have.

Comment: Kermit sorry does that help

Comment: @Kermit any thoughts on how to massage this data? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using pure JS and the YQL API.

```
var yql_query = 'select * from html where url="http://www.scorespro.com/soccer/england/premier-league/2014-2015/standings/"';
yql_query += " and xpath='//*[@id=\"standings_1a\"]'";
yql_query = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(yql_query) + '&format=html&callback=?';

$.getJSON(yql_query, function (data) {

    // do something crazy the power is now yours! $(data.results[0])
});
```